# Changing name of top-level directory when downloading a tarball from GitHub?

Tags: git, github

I am trying to download the latest version of a specific github branch with curl.

```
curl -L https://github.com/nativescript/docs/tarball/production | tar zx
```

However, this creates a file such as `NativeScript-docs-ed0d16f` whihc is difficult to work with in code as the name will change for every commit. Is there a way to download that file, but for the folder to be called `docs-latest` from the command line?

Without knowing the name of the downloaded file?

Comment: This has nothing to do with curl - curl is writing to stdout so it's not doing anything with file names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the newer `.../archive/...` link rather than the `.../tarball/...` link in your question.  The general format is:

```
https://github.com/<group_or_organization>/<repo>/archive/<refspec>.tar.gz
```

So, for example:

```
$ curl -L jttps://github.com/nativescript/docs/archive/production.tar.gz | tar tz
docs-production/
docs-production/.gitattributes
docs-production/.gitignore
docs-production/.gitmodules
docs-production/.vscode/
docs-production/.vscode/settings.json
docs-production/README.md
...
```

You can see that the generated top-level directory name uses whatever `<refspec>` you provided, rather than converting it into a commit id.

Similarly:

```
$ curl -s -L https://github.com/nativescript/docs/archive/ErikEdits-css-annimations.tar.gz   | tar tz
docs-ErikEdits-css-annimations/
docs-ErikEdits-css-annimations/.gitattributes
docs-ErikEdits-css-annimations/.gitignore
...
```

In place of a branch name you can use other `git` [refspecs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#_specifying_revisions).  For example:

```
https://github.com/nativescript/docs/archive/HEAD^.tar.gz
```

Or:

```
https://github.com/nativescript/docs/archive/v2.3.0-20-ged0d16f.tar.gz
```

But in these cases, the reference *will* be converted into a commit id.

Answer (score 0):

larsks' answer does not work for me. GitHub's API must have changed at least once since his answer was written or I'm doing something different. But also I wanted to download a tarball, not a zip file.

For **GNU tar** it is simple:

```
--one-top-level[=DIR]
    Extract all files into DIR, or, if used without argument, into a subdirectory
    named by the base name of the archive
```

So `tar --one-top-level -xvf ${release_file}.tar.gz` answers your question from the title and will extract contents into a folder named `${release_file}`. `${release_file}` is obviously a placeholder I have chosen here.

For **non-GNU** systems (macOS, BSD?) you have to decide if you want to do some [risky¹ attempt at identifying the folder name](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/246807/49853) or [strip the top level folder](https://serverfault.com/a/330131) name and create it yourself. So I decided to do the latter and did this for GitHub in my script:

```bash
mkdir -pv "${release_file}"

tar -C "${release_file}" \
  --strip-components 1 \
  -xvf "${release_file}.tar.gz"
```

---

¹It now seems risky to me. With dowloading from Github on a repo you trust you are probably fine most of the time. But if you really care about security you should treat the file and contained file list as untrusted. Years ago I voted on Naga's answer and it looked fine to me. But today working with bash strict mode and after taking [LFD121](https://training.linuxfoundation.org/training/developing-secure-software-lfd121/) it looks risky to me.